# How to center navigation bar items CSS

Tags: html, css, center, navbar

I have a navigation bar that it spanning the entire page's width. I've also added a jQuery script so that it changes to position:fixed after scrolling for a bit, but I don't think that will influence this issue.

My issue is that I can't get the navigation bar `<li>`'s to center. I've tried countless things I've found on the internet, and even downloaded some templates to splice in. No luck. I'm sure I'm just missing something, but I'd like the `<li>`'s to go smack-dab in the middle of the navbar, but everything I've tried either makes them slightly off, floats them to the left, or makes them not resize properly.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Blah blah blah</h1>

        <!--START NAVBAR-->
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a>Home</a></li>
                <li><a>Home</a></li>
                <li><a>Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--STOP NAVBAR-->

        <div class="content">
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
            </p>
            <p>

            Nullam pellentesque nunc luctus...
            </p><p>
            Donec sodales fermentum orci...
            </p><p>
            Ut venenatis tellus ...
            </p><p>
            Nullam quis molestie nunc...

            </p>
        </div>

    </body>
```

And the CSS:

```
body{
background-image:url("woodPatternShadow.png");
background-size:75% auto;
padding:0;
font-family:"Verdana";
}



.nav{
height:40px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
left:0;
right:0;
box-shadow: inset 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), inset 0 10px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3),inset 0 10px 20px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset 0 -15px 30px rgba(28,0,0,0.3);
border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
margin:0;
position:absolute;
}

#fixNav{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
}

.nav ul{
}

.nav ul li{
}

.nav ul li a{
}

.content{
background-color:white;
border-radius:20px;
padding:10px;
width:70%;
margin:100px auto 0;
}
```

The empty selectors are the places where I can't figure it out.

Can someone clear this up for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `ul` to have `text-align: center` and set `display: inline-block` on the `li` elements.

```
.nav ul {
   list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
}

.nav ul li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Elements with `display: inline-block` are treated as inline elements even though they act like block elements in most respects, so setting `text-align: center` on the container will center the inline `li` elements inside of it.

Obviously this is a barebones functional answer - you will need to add styles to adjust presentation of the `li` and `a` elements.  All this code does is remove the default bullets and centers the `li` elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had tried this before, but there must've been another property conflicting with it. One more thing, though: There are spaces in between the `<li>`'s, here: http://imgur.com/O2k3E6X Is there any way to fix this? I'm planning on having borders, so they need to be right next to each other.

Comment: Try adding `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` to `.nav ul li`.  Typically in these cases I like to reset the `li` container so it has no properties of its own (e.g. no width or height or padding etc) and then just let the `a` styles take care of the visual aspects (so add your border and padding, etc to the `.nav ul li a` rather than `.nav ul li` definitions).

Comment: Hm.. Putting on the `margin:0` and `padding:0` on any of the elements doesn't seem to work... EDIT: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3e8st/

Comment: @user2779909 if you can recreate the issue in a JSFiddle I'm sure I could fix it!  It is probably a whitespace issue though.  Try removing the line breaks between your `li` elements (so it should be like `<li><a href="example.html">Example Link</a></li><li><a href="#">Example 2</a></li>` with no whitespace or line breaks between the `li`s)

Comment: If it is indeed whitespace causing the spacing, instead of the above method, set `font-size: 0` on the `.nav ul` and then explicitly define the `font-size` on either `.nav ul li` or `.nav ul li a`.

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that! That fixed it, thanks. I put the fiddle in the above comment if you still want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

There's always

```
text-align: center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M4Q5h/

Then there's:

```
.nav ul li{
    display: table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gnM5f/

2nd is probably the best way but if you want text centered anyway then the first might be fine (EDIT: In which case Ennui's answer is more complete).

Answer (score 0):

Apply `list-style:none` and `text-align:center` to `.nav` class.

**CSS**:

```
.nav{
    ----
    ----
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mPhGZ/)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying about width... If I shouldn't add width (or height) because it's clunky, how can I specify, well, the width? Would I use padding, instead?

Comment: @user2779909 I have removed it since it has confused you. What I tried to say was that if you specify width for list elements then it will be needed further editing in CSS while adding a new list element.

Answer (score 0):

just add this

```css
nav {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: consolas;
    align-items: center;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    float: center;
    color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav align="center">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Videos</a>
        <a href="#">Resources</a>
        <a href="#">Projects</a>
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
    </nav>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).